# Reproducible way to ID an element on a page

Tags: javascript, dom, serialization, hash

An interesting problem:

I want to have a reproducible way to identify elements on a page such that I can store this ID and be able to id the element on another client, without having to store the full HTML. It needs, also, to be robust to insertion / removal of nodes in the DOM (so a simple numbering convention will not work).

So far, Im thinking:
In certain cases we will have a unique `id` which i can use, falling back to offset from the first parent that does have an id attached, else parent that has a class attached. Does this make sense? Am I missing a trick?

Kind of related: [What information about a DOM element would allow JavaScript to identify it (somewhat) uniquely? (e.g. when it doesn't have `id`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367778/what-information-about-a-dom-element-would-allow-javascript-to-identify-it-somew)

Comment: Are you in control of the page contents (and hence ID elements), or do you have to adapt to existing pages?  Also, do you have to handle all general cases (which might give you less useful domain information), or do you have a specific format (which might be more interesting/useful to consumers of those pages)?  If possible, I'd personally prefer more useful domain information (while still handling data/page variation) over an all-encompassing solution.  As Grooveek said, the all-encompassing version can already be encoded as XPath queries.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the page or contents, and I have to handle the absolutely general case, with minimal assumptions as to structure of the page beforehand, so domain information will be largely out of the picture

Comment: If you can't control your input at a global, all-time level, it might still be possible to add support for new known data schemas incrementally.  If not, then you've stumped me.  This sounds like an interesting problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to know a robust XPath () for any element
An ID would be a Base64 version, or a hash version of the XPath of the element

That question sounds a bit weird to me, no offense. If you don't functionnally or semantically define each element in the DOM, what identify it is precisely its position in the DOM, or if you want the relationship it has with other element in the DOM...

The fifth row of a table could have a functional definition (depending on the application, eg in a mail box app, its something like ), but it can also be the fifth element of a table... The information about the element is made by the intent of the developer, not by a magic formula describing every html element ever made

Correct me If I misunderstood your point

Cheers

Grooveek

Comment: +1 for XPath, and using the hash of the XPath to create a unique ID for that particular path.

Comment: The problem in that case would be to have a deterministic way to find a good XPath for an element. I'm not sure an algorithm exists for that :-)

Comment: Hey, Thanks - I considered xpaths, but my concern is with the element, invariant to position in the DOM. xpaths can change very substantially when you add elements - suspect an ID / xpath hybrid is more robust?

Comment: It would probably be difficult, but I'm leaning towards it being possible :)  I'd speculate on solutions, but I'm not 100% sure if this is the best option for him.  It is a solution, though, hence the upvote.

Comment: Im considering hashing the innerHTML :D