# Is possible to get an unique id of HTML tag without using the id field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to understand if there's the chance to get an unique id from an HTML tag/node without using the id attribute on the tag, my situation is something like that:

```
<!-- div #1 -->
<div style="width:200px; height:200px;"><script src="myScript.js"></script></div>
<!-- div #2-->
<div style="width:200px; height:200px;"><script src="myScript.js"></script></div>
```

With myScript.js I'd like to identify both of divs in a unique way, something like:

```
//pseudo code of myScript.js
// let ids = [];
for(element in dom){
    if(dom[element] is one_of_the_div_I_was_looking_for){
        ids.push(dom[element].uniqueDivIdentifier);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

More info about the case:

1. I can't add any kind of attributes in the divs.
2. I can't use jQuery
3. I won't be the one who will create the HTML structure
4. n° of divs is random, even the position and the dimensions in style attribute, so I could have also `<div style="width:300px; height:250px;"><script src="myScript.js"></script></div>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Consider using jQuery for this, if you can use libraries, to ease the pain of writing more than needed js. https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: @HarishST no, I'm not lucky in this situation :)

Comment: @Anuga I can't use jQuery, plain js only

Comment: Here is a similar question. The conversation there will give you some ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367778/what-information-about-a-dom-element-would-allow-javascript-to-identify-it-some

Comment: Can you store information about the document separate from the document?

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara I've added more infos btw I can store stuff only in the document scopre where `myScript` runs.

Comment: For downvoters , please add the motivation. Feedback are always welcomed.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the bottom-line, which way to go matters a lot on what for, and how these elements are supposed to be used/accessed, and none of that is mentioned in your question (which also might be one reason you get downvotes).

Comment: Since we don't get any feedback I decided to delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the order in which they appear, then in a list such as that returned by `querySelectorAll`, the first one will be before the second one. Example:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#container div");
var n = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  list[n].classList.remove("highlight");
  n = n == 0 ? 1 : 0;
  list[n].classList.add("highlight");
}, 500);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!-- div #1 -->
  <div style="width:200px; height:200px;">testing 1 2 3</div>
  <!-- div #2-->
  <div style="width:200px; height:200px;">testing 1 2 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- id selectors
- class selectors
- libraries like jQuery..

but if you don't want to modify html, you can even select by style attribute,(not the best approach ...)

```js
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('*[style="width:200px; height:200px;"]');
elms[0].style.background='red';
```

```css
7
```

```html
<!-- div #1 -->
  <div style="width:200px; height:200px;">testing 1 2 3</div>
  <!-- div #2-->
  <div style="width:200px; height:200px;">testing 1 2 3</div>
```